# Error compiler, cannot convert parameter 2 from MyStruct1 to const void*, for memcpy

Tags: c++, c, memcpy

I am trying to copy the data from on structure to another. The bytes are identical that each struct can handle are the same. My declarations and the memcpy are below:

```
    typedef struct{
        CString strNumber;
        CString strAlpha;

    } _Number;

    typedef struct{
        CString strIterration;
        _Number NumberOne;
        _Number NumberTwo;
    } _Store;

_Store Data1;
_Store Data2;
```

Now let's say that the first struct Data1 has data and the second is just declared.

I am using the following code:

```
memcpy(&Data2, Data1,   sizeof(_Store));
```

I cannot compile as the error appears. Any ideas? Any other approaches to copy the data?

Comment: The names `_Number` and `_Store` are illegal in your code (the prefixes `_A` - `_Z` reserved for the compiler's internal use). Furthermore, in C++ you don't need to typedef struct's. So: `struct Number { CString strNumber; CString strAlpha; };`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `&` on both structs:

```
memcpy(&Data2, &Data1, sizeof(_Store));
```

Beware: `_Store` contains `CString` member variable which (if it is like MFC `CString`) is not bitwise copyable. You should only use `memcpy()` on types that are bitwise copyable, otherwise you risk running into undefined behavior.

Comment: It works, thanks a bunch! Some aside questions: Data1 is not altered why is called as reference? And still, undefined behaviour? Meaning? My exe returned badly:

Comment: @Sunscreen: Supposedly, `CString` is more than a bunch of bytes (it will likely contain a pointer to some memory allocated on the heap), and you can't just `memcpy` it. Geoff's answer has the right approach: just use the assignment operator.

Comment: /*
         * If this ASSERT fails, a bad pointer has been passed in. It may be
         * totally bogus, or it may have been allocated from another heap.
         * The pointer MUST come from the 'local' heap.
         */
        _ASSERTE(_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData));

Comment: @Sunscreen: & in front of a variable is taking the address (obtaining pointer to object), not passing a reference. `memcpy` expects pointers.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious other approach is simple assignment, i.e., Data2 = Data1;

This saves you from caring how many bytes are in the _Store structure and also from whether CString has an operator =.